# Get a reference to the class of the calling function

Tags: kotlin

When I have two classes (A and B) and A has a function called myFunA which then calls myFunB (inside of class B), is it possible for code in myFunB to obtain a reference to the class A that is used to call myFunB? I can always pass the reference as a parameter but I am wondering if Kotlin has a way of allowing a function to determine the instance of the parent caller.

```
class A {
    fun myFunA() {
        val b = B()

        b.myFunB() {

        }
    }
}

class B {
    fun myFunB() {
       // Is it possible to obtain a reference to the instance of class A that is calling
       // this function?
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I don't believe it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
interface BCaller {
    fun B.myFunB() = myFunB(this@BCaller)
}

class A : BCaller {
    fun myFunA() {
        val b = B()
        b.myFunB()
    }
}

class B {
    fun myFunB(bCaller: BCaller) {
        // you can use `bCaller` here
    }
}
```

---

If you need a reflection-based approach, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072542/can-i-get-the-instance-of-the-calling-object-in-java).

Comment: I wrote: "I can always pass the reference as a parameter..." - I was looking for a solution that doesn't pass it as a parameter. After all, if Kotlin knows the call stack, you would think that maybe it could somehow inform the called function what the instance is of the class calling it is.